# c# httpwebrequest to a web page iphone version

Tags: c#, iphone, request

i want to make an httwebrequest to a web page and get the response html of that page.

the problem is i want to generate the request as i'm requesting it on iPhone so that the website gives me the iphone version of the page

some told me to set the user agent to some string.. i did but its not working i think i need to modify some other headers of the request.

appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting your hostheader to `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3` should be enough.

If not, the website has done some additional detection, but therefore we'd need the webaddress.